# Does the Eco-Cooler reduce temperatures in tin huts by around 5° Celsius, compared to simple windows?

Tags: physics

The [zero-electricity Eco-Cooler made from plastic bottles](https://plastics-themag.com/Eco-cooler:-An-eco-friendly-air-conditioner-made-of-plastic-bottles-that-does-not-use-electricity) is doing the rounds all over the interwebs:

> The principle is a simple one: the plastic bottles are cut in half and glued to a board or a grille. The latter is then installed in a window frame, with the necks of the bottles facing towards the inside of the house. The system works as follows: the hot air that enters each bottle is compressed around the neck of the bottle, cooling it down before it enters the room. The neck of the bottle acts as a tunnel that compresses the air. This cools the air when it exits the neck of the bottle (rapid expansion) using the same principle. The cooling effect following rapid expansion is known as the Joule-Thomson effect. Depending on the direction of the wind and the pressure exerted, the Eco-Cooler can reduce the temperature by five degrees, which is the same amount as an electric air conditioner.
> …
> Over 70% of Bangladesh’s population live in corrugated tin huts across the countryside. During the long summer months, temperatures reach up to 45° Celsius, making these huts unbearable to live in.
>
> To address the issue, Grey Dhaka teamed up with volunteers from Grameen Intel Social Business Ltd to create the Eco-Cooler – the world’s first-ever zero electricity air cooler, which uses re-purposed plastic bottles cut in half and put into a grid, in accordance to available window sizes. Based on wind direction and airflow pressure, the Eco-Cooler has succeeded in decreasing the temperature in tin huts by up to 5° Celsius.

Does the Eco-Cooler reduce temperatures in tin huts by around 5° Celsius, compared to simple windows?

Comment: See also a recent [chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30283600#30283600) and the same question on [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/261284/how-does-the-eco-cooler-air-conditioner-really-work)

Comment: I looked up the claim instead of paraphrasing it, the question is now answerable with facts and not mere speculation...

Comment: As far as I understand the claim, this thing is supposed to work because (a) it provides shade and protection from rain, an a simple hole window does not and (b) it's meant to catch transverse wind and funnel it in the hut. On the other hand, it's certainly an obstruction that (c) reduces the free circulation of air, which is very important if the hut is hotter than the outside.

Comment: I'm leaving the comment here in the hope that our answerers understand that any theoretical answer is not only not acceptable here, but likely wildly off the mark. Any general principle that relies on a closed system (e.g. conservation of energy,  laws of thermodynamics) is not applicable here.

Comment: The link in the question is now broken and no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I found a paper studying the effectiveness of this sort of air cooler. [Link](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1757-899X/1006/1/012005/pdf)

Table 2 (Page 7) of the paper states that the reduction achieved was less than 1C over an hour, which contradicts the claim of a 5C reduction. Enhanced models (with water added) tested in the document also show reductions of 1.4 and 1.9C over an hour, which is far from the claim of 5C

Comment: The data in the study is for a much cooler temperature in the claim which is likely to have an impact on the results. Also it appears to be focusing on cooling over a period of time instead of total amount that it can cool. It would also help if you provided data from the paper in your answer instead of expecting people to read the paper and understand it.

Comment: Even though the paper does not research maximum cooling capabilities, I think it is still a good find. Especially since the "Reduction in temp." declines so much over time, one could draw the conclusion that the maximum difference in temperature achievable will not be much higher than what was achieved in the study.

Comment: @JoeW, all cooling is ‘cooling over time’ as no cooling is instant. It is very fair to say max cooling temperature over 1 hour is likely the max achievable as that is enough time for the system to reach steady state. Meaning, the energy input equals energy extraction (effectively what heating/cooling is).

Comment: With that said, the starting temperature of such a system can indeed impact the achievable delta.

Comment: @JarrodChristman You would need to show evidence that the cooling stops and doesn't actually reach the claimed amount and use the correct temperatures that the system is expected to operate in.  Just because it doesn't cool that much in a single hour doesn't mean that it can't reach it over a longer period. Even an AC unit can take longer then an hour to cool down an area to the desired temperature and we shouldn't expect faster cooling from an unpowered unit.

Comment: @JoeW, if anything you should expect an unpowered cooling device to reach steady state sooner, it doesn’t have a continual energy input like an AC. I suspect that is why they choose the time span they did.

Comment: @JoeW, keep in mind an AC can reach steady state as well, where no matter the time, it will not go lower. If you’re in the environment where you’ll use such an unpowered device, you’re also very likely to not be in the most insulated and well built building or room. Even if the paper is doing a rate of cooling, my point is it very likely is close to the steady state.

Comment: @JarrodChristman Yes, I understand that, the point being that judging the final temperature that can be cooled by a system when you are using it in conditions that are 20C or more lower then the claimed temperatures and artificially limiting how long you can run it for will give you bad data. The study is using 25-27C temp range (which you don't even need cooling in the first place) instead of the 45C+ range that is made by the claim. When you are dealing with something that is 20C cooler then the claim there is a lot less heat to be taken out of the air.

Comment: @JoeW, yes, I didn’t take issue with that, I explicitly stated the starting temperature can indeed impact (absolute) delta. However, delving into the paper (I’ve been traveling so haven’t had a chance), they did take into consideration the saturation of the device. They appeared to wait until 4 consecutive intervals had the same (or near) temperatures. Further, it looks like they measured the outlet temp and room temp. If the two match, you’re obviously at saturation. The room can’t get colder than the outlet temp. I’ll keep reading, maybe there is a way to model its performance over a range

Comment: @JoeW, yeah, based on that paper alone, a general model can’t be developed as the performance depends on air velocity and efficiency may vary with external temperature. There are equations for the Venturi effect, but it gets complex as temperature can affect the optimal chock point diameter. Almost too many variables, which is probably why the paper resorted to a mix of computer modeling and direct testing. I think you may have a hard time finding an authoritative source for the specifics in the claim and would require original research in the form of a custom fluid model and experimental test

Comment: Rather than the reduction in temperature, wouldn't the appropriate comparison be between a room with this device and a similar room with an open window?  (E.g. the sun could be slowly heating up the room, so a small temperature reduction could actually be a large reduction, but no one can say without a control to compare it to.)